# R Shiny Crashing for invalid user input (Error argument of length 0)

Tags: r, shiny

I'm working on an R Shiny app that that allows users to enter their own formulas for a given model. When users enter an invalid input (say two plus signs in a row), the app crashes with the following error:

`Warning: Error in :: argument of length 0`

I'm having trouble controlling user input and locating where exactly the error arises. The object is a data frame/list. I've tried to use if loops with `is.na` and `is.null` as a condition but I still get this error. How could one control for this error in Shiny, say for any invalid input that the user could enter?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi @dsgfsg, welcome to Stack Overflow. It's difficult for us to help you without  a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your issue. That way we can recreate your problem ourselves. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tryCatch` for the code you are worried will return an error. This will return the data you want if the input is correct, and will return something else e.g. `NA` if there is an error.

You can check the `processed_data` for the indication of an error e.g. `is.na(processed_data)` and do something based on that error.

```
display_user_input <- renderUI({
processed_data  <- tryCatch({
  processed_data  <- my_function(input$user_input)
  processed_data
}, error =  function(e) {
  xx <- NA
  processed_data
},warning =  function(e) {
  xx <- NA
  processed_data 
})

if(is.na(processed_data)){
helpText("User input not valid")
}else{
##do something with processed data
renderTable(processed_data)
}
})
```